# Not able to remember selection with BufferedStore when scroll down and go back to original selection

Tags: extjs

I was working on continuous scrolling using BufferedStore and calling bufferedrender plugin from my grid. The continuous scrolling is working perfectly but the selection of my records are not getting retained(remembered) when I scroll down and go back to my original selection.

I also tried with the property pruneRemoved : false in selection model. Still the issue persists. Could you please help us on this how can we proceed further.

Version of ExtJS : 6.0.2

Comment: Have you specified the `idProperty` in your `Ext.data.Model`?

Comment: Yes Andy. Problem is with idProperty. I actually added that but we realized that was being added incorrectly and forgot to update here. Thank you any way.